# Warning: Shipping method required - OpenCart

Tags: php, opencart

Ran into this problem a while back. Been scouring the web, OpenCart forums, StackOverflow for weeks now trying to get this sorted.

![enter image description here][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fbDB.png

Basically I took Flat Shipping module and made a copy of it. Renamed every instance of module name and got myself another flat rate shipping module.

Only problem is that I get this warning which doesn't throw any errors. This seems to be a fairly common problem but every solution that I found didn't help me.

I noticed that if I enable Free shipping module I can select it no warnings. But when I go to select my custom shipping module I get a warning.

If anyone has a solution or what else I can check I'd appreciate the tip.

I am working with OpenCart 1.5.6.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is almost certainly going to be due to your model file for your shipping method. Make sure that you've given the new method code for the items. For example, the original shipping method would use `flat.flat` which if you view the HTML for the radio on your site you'll see what yours is. Basically if your new one is `new.new` then make sure you've set this accordingly in your model file

Comment: I called mine ``irlukflat.flat`` like so ``<input type="radio" name="shipping_method" value="irlukflat.flat" id="irlukflat.flat" checked="checked">``. I will try ``irlukflat.irlukflat`` tonight just to make sure.

Comment: You're welcome iiminov. Glad it's solved. I faced the same issue when I first started developing for OC :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you notice, this error arises when the page is reloaded and so I thought it had to do with the cache since when I experienced it, I always had to clear cache and then it would not bring that.
Read this to get some insight on whether the solution applies to your case [cause of error](https://github.com/opencart/opencart/issues/7008)

open system/framework.php in your open cart installation, locate the line below (around line 74)

```
$response->addHeader('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Add the following lines immediately below it

```
$response->addHeader('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
$response->addHeader('Pragma: no-cache');
```

Now, clear your browser cache. The warning should no longer be there.